# How to read all shared google reader feeds by code?

Tags: .net, asp.net, feed, google-reader

I share a lot of feeds on my google reader, i want some code using asp.net to read all these feeds and put in a page, may be with paging because feeds are too much.
Any one know how to do so?, or if there is a tool for that

Comment: You want to aggregate all your RSS feeds into one huge RSS feed?

Comment: just want to get the marked as shared feeds to put in a page, to make paging in the feeds and show in different ways, i put it as iframe in my site http://igurr.com/content/IGurrShare.aspx but i want to read it by code to show as i want not inside iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [RSSToolkit](http://blogs.msdn.com/shahpiyush/archive/2007/06/16/3331941.aspx) to read the shared feeds

Answer (score 3):

You can find a Atom feed for you feeds here:
http://www.google.com/reader/atom/

You can find a more specific url, if you login into Google Reader and click the RSS button, in the top of your browser.

Then you just need something to read your feeds.
Here's a third party library for that purpose.
http://atomnet.sourceforge.net/

It's very simple to use

```
//Reads everything in the Atom document.
AtomFeed feed = AtomFeed.Load(new Uri("http://www.yourfeed.com/atom.xml");
```

Comment: Where is the 3rd part library?

Answer (score 1):

I think Google reader does not have an official API as of now. But found [this one](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2005/12/google-reader-api.html) for you. This also has shared items. check out.

Update: Google reader has an [API](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2005/12/google-reader-api.html#comment8093)

Answer (score 0):

I found this one as well and it seams nice:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/rssframework.aspx